# Program utilizing ibapi is running but will not print live data

Tags: python-3.x, ib-api

Here is my code that I am trying to run let :

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import threading

class MyWrapper(EWrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        EWrapper.__init__(self)

    def nextValidId(self, orderId):
        print(f"Setting nextValidOrderId: {orderId}")
        # Start program here or use threading
        # app.reqContractDetails(4444, contract)

    def contractDetails(self, reqId, contractDetails):
        print(reqId, contractDetails.contract)

    def contractDetailsEnd(self, reqId):
        print(f"ContractDetailsEnd. {reqId}")
        # This is the logical end of your program

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print(f"Error. Id: {reqId}, Code: {errorCode}, Msg: {errorString}")

    def tickPrice(self, tickerid, tickType, price, attrib):
        global i
        i += 1
        print(f"{i} Tick type: {tickType}, Price: {price}")

    def tickSize(self, tickerid, tickType, size):
        global i
        i += 1
        print(f"{i} Tick type: {tickType}, Size: {size}")

    def tickString(self, tickerid, tickType, value):
        global i
        i += 1
        print(f"{i} Tick type: {tickType}, Value: {value}")

    def tickGeneric(self, tickerid, tickType, value):
        global i
        i += 1
        print(f"{i} Tick type: {tickType}, Value: {value}")

wrapper = MyWrapper()
app = EClient(wrapper)
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, clientId=1)
print(f"Server Version: {app.serverVersion()}, Connection Time: {app.twsConnectionTime()}")

contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = "EUR"
contract.secType = "CASH"
contract.currency = "USD"
contract.exchange = "IDEALPRO"  # Use IDEALPRO for forex

app.reqMktData(1, contract, "", False, False, [])
print(app.isConnected())

i = 0  # Initialize i for tick counts

app.run()
```

I see this as the output in visual studio code when I run the above python program:

**Server Version: 157, Connection Time: b'20231027 13:34:45 EST'
True**

How do I fixed this code so I can see live data printed? Thanks in advance. what do you think is the problem? Can anyone help me get live data from interactive brokers' ibapi